# Looking for a C# or Java or Python or C++ example to control Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, python, windows, api, remote-desktop

We have a hard policy that all computers must lock after 15 minutes of inactivity.

FOR GUI testing using `CodedUI` library, it is important that the connection is on, and that the screen is not locked. So, to circumvent the checks, I was thinking of writing a script in Python, etc. which would make the connection alive by ... say, hitting a "Windows" twice every 5 minutes.

I searched online and found nothing that seems relevant. Any suggestions?

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=remote+desktop+api&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m4&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=3f8c1f6954acb9e1

*EDIT:*

Thanks to Paul Sasik for asking me to clarify. Yes, I just need some sort of solution that would work.

Comment: Seems strange that you're not allowed to turn off the 15 min lockdown on a development machine,  but you are allowed to write an app to circumvent it.  I'd just ask your management whether they want tests running or not.

Comment: @James, yes, I feel my pain ;), but things can be hard to arrange at a very LARGE organization, plus some industries are more paranoid than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be remote? Whatever your solution you need some sort of service/daemon running on the target machine. Since you need that anyway, why not create a small app that simply emulates user interaction locally by moving a window or just sends a click to the desktop?

Here's an [MSDN article that describes emulating mouse and keyboard events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx). Could be a start or exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you Paul, this is a good start indeed. I worry about messing up the existing CodedUI tests. I think that sending a Windows key to the desktop would work just fine, but how do I do that? How do I send messages to the desktop and not any application in particular?

Comment: That's right. It could come from any app. To send to the desktop all you have to do is get the window with handle NULL. But that may affect the focus of the app.